# Mobx/Storybook: Need to configure Storybook to work with Mobx-State-Tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, storybook

I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` error for more than 80% of my components when I attempt to view them in StoryBook.

I'm thinking I need to either mock out the data in the story or pass the corresponding stores into it but I'm not sure. I reached out to the [Storybook Discord](https://discordapp.com/channels/486522875931656193/501692020226654208) channel and someone suggested wrapping them inside a `<Provider>` but I don't know how to pull that off inside Storybook.

I've created a basic outline of both my component and the corresponding story file below. Any help or suggestions with this would be hugely appreciated!

`Component`

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import { RootStoreModel } from '../../stores/root-store'
import useInject from '../../hooks/useInject'

const mapStore = ({ componentSummary, customer }: RootStoreModel) => ({
    item1: parent.data.item1,
    item2: parent.data.item2
    item3:  parent.data.item3
})

type Props = {
    idx: number;
    title: string;
    toggleActive: (idx: number, newState: false) => void;
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props): JSX.Element => {
    const {
    item1,
    item2,
    item3
    } = useInject(mapStore)

    const { idx, title, toggleActive } = props

    return (
        <div>Content</div>
        )
}

export default observer(MyComponent)
```

`Story file for component`

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import MyComponent from './myComponent';

const options = ['done', 'error', 'pending'];

storiesOf('My Component', module)
    .add(
        'Default', () =>
            <MyComponent idx={0} title="ComponentNumeroUno" toggleActive={() => null}/>,
    );
```